# BLE MESH - Better option to implement OnOff mesh network using esp32 - Group address or Element address?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, mesh-network

I am developing a BLE mesh network application with more than 20 - 30 ESP32 as nodes and in each node, I am implementing 5-7 elements. All elements implement Generic OnOff server and client models. Which type of address would be a better option to control the on/off of each element- group address or element address or both at the same time to implement the network?